# Save and restore terminal tabs with custom tabs title

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, command-line, gnome-shell

I have a Terminal window with a dozen named tabs open *(gnome-terminal)
I would like to save the current configuration and have it restored with names and directories.
Is there a way to do this?

I've found a solution from another user question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/310705/some-fast-way-to-save-and-restore-tabs-of-terminal/310750#310750

It worked fine except for the saving and renaming of the tabs. I don't have xdotools installed and i don't have the privilege to install it as this is my office workstation. Is there any workaround on this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have to permissions to (or can convince your SysAdmin), I suggest looking into [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) which is a terminal multiplexer. Tmux allows you to do everything you are talking about and more. You can have it manage all your windows and just detach your session when done. Picking up were you left off is as easy as reattaching to your detached session ([one of many guides](https://danielmiessler.com/study/tmux/)). My current tmux session manages over 30+ 'tabs' right now, so I can always pause my work at the end of the day and quickly pick up again where I left off the next day.

You can even nest your tabs within your same windows! Example of window control:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an xfce terminal fork, with possibility to save/restore session just from menu: https://github.com/repu1sion/xfce4-terminal

Comment: Could you please update your answer to include steps to complete the task you are suggesting? It is better to include the steps instead of just linking to a different step.

Answer (score 0):

tabby(https://github.com/Eugeny/tabby) can be a solution for this.
Just open multiple tabs and move folder. It will be there after closing and opening the tabby.